# Query or VBA Function for adding leading zeroes to a field with special conditions

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a macro I am trying to turn into a VBA Function or Query for adding leading zeros to a field.

For my circumstances, their needs to be 4 numeric digits plus any alphabetic characters that follow so a simple format query doesn't do the trick.

The macro I have uses Evaluate and =Match but I am unsure how this could be achieved in Access.

```
Sub Change_Number_Format_In_String()
   Dim iFirstLetterPosition As Integer
   Dim sTemp As String
   For Each c In Range("A2:A100")
       If Len(c) > 0 Then
          iFirstLetterPosition = Evaluate("=MATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISNUMBER(1*MID(" & c.Address &      ",ROW($1:$20),1))),0)")
          sTemp = Left(c, iFirstLetterPosition - 1) 'get the leading numbers
          sTemp = Format(sTemp, "0000") 'format the numbers
          sTemp = sTemp & Mid(c, iFirstLetterPosition, Len(c)) 'concatenate the remainder of the string
          c.NumberFormat = "@"
          c.Value = sTemp
       End If
    Next
End Sub
```

In my database the field in need of formatting is called `PIDNUMBER`

EDIT:

To expand on why FORMAT doesnt work in my situation.  Some PIDNUMBERS have an alpha character after the number that should not be counted when determining how many zeroes to add.

In example:

12 should become 0012

12A should become 0012A

When using format, it counts the letters as part of the string, so 12A would become 012A instead of 0012A as intended.

Comment: It's VBA, you can use anything from any COM object. So something like `dim xl as excel:xl.evaluate("blah")` (you have to add excel to References).

Comment: Can you expand on your requirements with some examples? It's not clear why `Format` can't be used.

Comment: Edited to clarify why Format cant be used.

Comment: Thanks again to everyone who replied, your efforts were useful in helping me understand how to approach this problem from more than one direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
Public Function customFormat(ByRef sString As String) As String
     customFormat = Right("0000" & sString, 4 + Len(sString) - Len(CStr(Val(sString))))
End Function
```

Comment: I'm choosing this as the answer because it is one line and straight forward.  This solution works with the same caveat as rdhs' solution above.  It adds an extra zero to numbers with a zero as the first digit if run a second time.  This is not an issue for my circumstances as the function is only run once during initial data import.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilize this function, if you only want this to be available in VBA, put `Private` in front of the **Function**:

```
Function ZeroPadFront(oIn As Variant) As String
    Dim zeros As Long, sOut As String
    sOut = CStr(oIn)
    zeros = 4 - Len(sOut)
    If zeros < 0 Then zeros = 0
    ZeroPadFront = String(zeros, "0") & sOut
End Function
```

Comment: This solution didn't work because it counts trailing letters as part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The `Val()` function converts a string to a number, and strips off any trailing non-numeric characters. We can use it to figure out how many digits the numeric portion has:

```
Function PadAlpha$(s$)
    Dim NumDigs As Long
    NumDigs = Len(CStr(Val(s)))
    If NumDigs < 4 Then
        PadAlpha = String$(4 - NumDigs, "0") & s
    Else
        PadAlpha = s
    End If
End Function

? padalpha("12")
> 0012

? padalpha("12a")
> 0012a
```

Comment: This looks like a suitable solution.  How would I execute this function on every record for a specified field?

Comment: This solution works.  The only caveat is that if run a second time numbers with zeroes get an extra digit added on.

Answer (score 0):

Bill,

See if this will work.  It seems like a function would better suit you.

```
Function NewPIDNumber(varPIDNumber As Variant) As String
Dim lngLoop As Long
Dim strChar As String

For lngLoop = 1 to Len(varPIDNumber)
    strChar = Mid(varPIDNumber, lngLoop, 1)
    If IsNumeric(strChar) Then
        NewPIDNumber = NewPIDNumber & strChar
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next lngLoop

If Len(NewPIDNumber) > 4 Then
    MsgBox "Bad Data Maaaaan...." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "The record = " & varPIDNumber
    Exit Function
End If

Do Until Len(NewPIDNumber) = 4
    NewPIDNumber = "0" & NewPIDNumber
Loop
End Function


Data    Result
012a    0012
12a     0012
12      0012
85      0085
85adfe  0085
1002a   1002
1002    1002
```

Comment: This solution didn't work.  It populated all records with "0000" overwriting the original contents.

Comment: I edited the code to fix some variable errors I made.  Also including the results.  Not sure how you are getting the zeros...

Comment: Oh I am missing the letters after the number in the result.  Either way, you already have found an answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at it, I appreciate it.